# Binary search - JS

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I'm trying to write a binary search function in JS that finds the first occurrence of '1' in a sorted array.
But I don't understand why I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop (my browser crashes) when I use while loop.

**here is the code I wrote so far**

```
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1];

function findTheOne(arr_start, arr_end, arr) {


    let mid = ((arr_start + arr_end)) / 2
    mid = Math.ceil(mid);

    while (arr_start <= arr_end) {
        if (arr[mid] == 1 && (mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] == 0)) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] == 1) {
            arr_end = mid - 1;
            console.log(arr_end);
        } else {
            arr_start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log(findTheOne(0, arr.length - 1, arr));
```

Comment: Because of: `arr_start = mid + 1` - you are never changing the value of `mid`, so the value of `arr_start` will be the same each time.  The same for `arr_end`.

Comment: Thanks mate! I didn't  noticed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop you never update the value of mid
you can just move your mid code inside the while loop.

```
const arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1];

function findTheOne(arr_start, arr_end, arr) {

    while (arr_start <= arr_end) {
        let mid = ((arr_start + arr_end)) / 2
        mid = Math.ceil(mid);
        if (arr[mid] == 1 && (mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] == 0)) {
            return mid;
        } else if (arr[mid] == 1) {
            arr_end = mid - 1;
            console.log(arr_end);
        } else {
            arr_start = mid + 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log(findTheOne(0, arr.length - 1, arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the value of `mid` inside the loop. If you move the first two lines of your function so that they are at the beginning of the loop, your code should work.